# .htaccess Auth for Staging site on a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, authentication, .htaccess, staging, litespeed

i am doing a WordPress staging site on a subdomain with a LiteSpeed server before put online.
I apologize but i have some questions.
Can i use the Auth of .htaccess to Hide the staging site? Are the LiteSpeed rules same of Apache rules?
I Have doubt .htaccess makes the site slow, are there some other ways?
Are there some more effectively, or further ways, such as not pointing the DNS of the subdomain, or change the Hosts File?
Which Is Better, Auth Digest or Auth Basic?
Think Auth Digest but i am not sure.
Thank you.

Don't try yet. These days i Will put the staging site with plesk, using .htaccess (not Apache, Litespeed).

Comment: This is a question we cannot really answer. Because you need to decide what you actually want to do. Certainly you can hide that staging site behind an auth wall, sure. Whether that is what you want, whether that is good or correct, that is something you need to decide. Whether a ".htaccess" file slows down the site - sure it does. But does that really matter in a staging site? An alternative is to implement such rules in the central http host configuration instead of using a _distributed_ configuration file.

Comment: Yes. Thank you arkascha. I think using the host rules Is the Better way. If i Will can not do It, i Will try the authentication of .htaccess.

Comment: You have to implement the same rules, regardless of whether you implement them in the central configuration or in a distributed configuration file. That mostly is a question of performance, complexity and configuration.